# Taking weights in consideration when using Apriori algorithm in R

Tags: r

Assuming I have the following dataset:

```
ID  Class   Sex     Age   Survived   Weights
1   3rd    Male    Child    No       64.88255201
2   1st    Male    Adult    yes      33.7458109
3   2nd    Female  Child    No       88.73229301
4   3rd    Male    Adult    yes      188.7209631
5   1st    Male    Adult    No       138.3900837
6   1st    Female  Child    No       27.12851097
7   3rd    Male    Adult    No       567.5111267
8   2nd    Female  Adult    No       33.61032299
```

I want to apply `apriori()` but taking in consideration the weight column I know that we can create a survey using the following code

```
    svy<- svydesign(id=~ID, 
                   weights=~ Weights,
                   data=mydata)
```

I am not sure how to integrate this so I can use `apriori()`

Comment: Please add packages you're using (`apriori` doesn't come shipped with R). What is the result you expect? What have you tried?

Comment: @Roman library(arules) for apriori algorithm

Comment: Did you manage to solve this eventually?